# How can I get specific file list without extra words?

Tags: batch-file

There are some file in folder, some file name rule like `[name]_[date].doc` (ex.: `aaa_20170727.doc`) and it also has some file rule like `[name]_[date]_org.doc` (ex.: `aaa_20170727_org.doc`).

If I use `dir *.doc /BO:N` it will output `[name]_[date].doc` and `[name]_[date]_org.doc` file list.

Question:

1. How can I only get the file name rule like `[name]_[date].doc`?
2. Is it possible using with for loop?

Comment: It is possible using `for` loop. And to only get `_org.doc`, you do `_*.doc`.

Comment: Here you go - I wrote an answer. If you find it useful, please tick the checkmark next to it, so future visitors know this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the name part does not contain underscores `_` on its own, and there is always a valid date part, you could use this (although this might still match some items with extra words):

```cmd
dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*_????????.doc"
```

If the date part could also be missing, or the name part could contain underscores as well, you could use `findstr` to filter out wrong matches, like this:

```cmd
dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*_????????.doc" | findstr /I "_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9].doc$"
```

Concerning `for` loop: I guess you want to iterate over the resulting files by a `for` loop; if so, you actually need a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (note the escaped pipe `^|`):

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*_????????.doc" ^| findstr /I "_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9].doc$"
') do (
    rem // Do something with each file:
    echo/%%F
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir` has no functionality to *ex*clude something. so you have to do it "external":

```
dir /b /o:n *.doc|find /i /v "_org.doc"
```

(Note: `dir` cannot concatenate switches like for example `findstr`: `dir /bo:n` doesn't work, use `dir /b /o:n`)

Comment: thank you so much.
I'm sorry there are some words missing and i update the question.